# getting the values from Objects in NSMutableArray (console)

Tags: objective-c

As newbie, Im stuck on getting the values from objects I have put in a NSMutableArray. To give a full picture of my problem I would appreciate you reading the following:

(writing to console in Xcode)

Lets say I produce a new object as follows:

```
Person *player = [[Person alloc] init];

player.age = 10;
player.height = 10;
player.name = @"player";
```

As I continue to write my programme I can change the above values of player i.e

```
player.age = 23; etc.....
```

If I want to create another Person (player2) I repeat the above like this:

```
Person *player1 = [[Person alloc] init];

player1.age = 13;
player1.height = 4;
player1.name = @"player1";
```

In my programme I can now change and compare values of the 2 objects i.e.

```
if (player.age == player1.age) bla bla bla
```

My problem starts if I want to create 20+ Person objects - I know how to place all the objects in a loop/NSMutableArray as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Person *player = [[Person alloc] init];

    player.age = 10;
    player.height = 10;
    player.name = @"player";
    [myArray addObject:player];       
    [player release];         
}
```

All the objects in myArray are individual but have the same values. Thats fine ! But how to get or change the objects in myArray ? (not at run time)

If [myArray objectAtIndex:4]; holds the following values:

```
player.age = 10;
player.height = 10;
player.name = @"player";
```

how do I get to the object(s) in myArray so I can compare/sort/add etc..

Heres example of what I want to do but I know is wrong:

```
if (player.age == [myArray personAtIndex:15.age];
```

or

```
NSLog(@"@ has a height of %i",[myArray personAtIndex:15:name:height];
```

prints out>> person has a height of 10

I really would appreciate you helping me on this - As a newbie I'm finding it hard to move on until I get an understanding of this problem. Thank you very much for reading this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating 20 objects in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514326/creating-20-objects-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You need to study the documentation for NSArray, in particular the `objectAtIndex` method.

```
[[(Person*)myArray objectAtIndex:15] age]
```

Will give you the value you want. I'll break this down:

- `(Person*)` tells the compiler that you expect to get a Person object back
- `objectAtIndex` returns an object (any object, hence the cast to Person above which prevents the compiler complaining that it might not respond to `age`) at index 15 of `myArray`
- `age` has to be called on the returned object because you can't use dot notation on cast objects

Alternatively, you could do:

```
Person *aPerson = (Person*)[myArray objectAtIndex:15];
aPerson.age = 15;
```

Once you have an object of known type you can use dot syntax.